# Как ограничить прямой доступ к php файлу, проблемы с загрузкой через ajax

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Почему при использовании **`defined('_EXEC') or die (header('Location: /home'));`** в ответ от ajax-запроса приходит совсем не та информация, по ощущения, что отрабатывает не тот запрос (хотя такое невозможно). А вот если без этой строки, то все работает как надо.

Т.е. в нормальном режиме загружается таблица, где в каждой строке есть кнопка "Удалить", при нажатии на нее, строка удаляется и страница ajax-ом обновляется, а вот с **`defined('_EXEC') or die (header('Location: /home'));`** после нажатия "Удалить" в место где должна была быть таблица, загружается информация с другой страницы.
Подскажите, как можно это исправить или как закрыть доступ к файлу, но чтоб все запросы отрабатывали.
Пробовал в **.htaccess** писать

```
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
```

но в итоге скрипты не отрабатывают.

Comment: А зачем вы при ajax запросе делаете переадресацию на другую страницу `header('Location: /home')`? Если у вас возникла ошибка при обработке ajax запроса, вы должны вернуть статус ошибки и чтобы javascript обработал ошибочную ситуацию на стороне клиента.

Comment: **defined('_EXEC') or die (header('Location: /home'));** - не в самом ajax-е, а в начале страницы, как и положено. В запросе ошибок не выдает, просто вместо нужной таблицы загружаются и вставляются другие данные.

Comment: Если у вас запрос с ajax идет к этой странице, то получите вы выполнение `die (header('Location: /home'));` как раз на него.

Comment: не к этой странице, а с этой страницы.

Comment: почему-то реально срабатывает **die**, но почему, если запрос идет **с** этой тсраницы